# TypeError: Cannot read property 'temperature' of null

Tags: reactjs, api, data-binding

I am a newbie to React - I am getting this `TypeError: Cannot read property 'temperature' of null` where it doesn't let me bind the temperature variable to the component in `return()`. I can see the data in console before binding it. 
Code : 
    `class App extends React.Component {
    state: {
    temperature: undefined,
    city: undefined,
    country: undefined,
    humidity: undefined,
    description: undefined,
    error: undefined
    }
    getWeather = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

```
const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
const country = e.target.elements.country.value;
const api_call = await 
fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
q=${city},${country}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`);
const data = await api_call.json();
console.log(data);
 this.setState({
   temperature: data.main.temp,
    city: data.name,
    country: data.sys.country,
    humidity: data.main.humidity,
    description: data.weather[0].description,
    error: ""
 });
}


render(){
return (
  <div>
    <h2>Check Weather Component</h2>
    <Titles />
    <Form getWeather={this.getWeather}/>
    <Weather
      temperature={this.state.temperature} 
      humidity={this.state.humidity}
      city={this.state.city}
      country={this.state.country}
      description={this.state.description}
      error={this.state.error}
              />

  </div>
 );
}
```

};

export default App;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component doesn't have any default state, so `this.state` will be `null` and trying to access the `temperature` property from that will give rise to your error.

Write `state = { ... }` instead of `state: { ... }` and your component will be given default state, and it will work as expected.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    temperature: undefined,
    city: undefined,
    country: undefined,
    humidity: undefined,
    description: undefined,
    error: undefined
  };

  // ...
}
```